# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') when i try to mute someone

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') error.

i get an error called **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')**, when i try to mute someone. how can i solve this.

mute file:

```js
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: "This command mutes a member!",
    execute(client, message, args) {
        const { member, mentions } = message
        const tag = `<@${member.id}>`
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (
            member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') ||
            member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')
        ) {
            if (target) {

                // let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');
                let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');

                let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

                if (!args[1]) {

                    // memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
                    memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                    message.channel.send(`${tag}, <@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted.`);
                    return
                }

                // memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                message.channel.send(`${tag}, <@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for **${ms(ms(args[1]))}**.`);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                    // memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);

                }, ms(args[1]));
            } else {
                message.channel.send(`${tag}, Please specify a user to mute.`);
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`${tag}, You do not have permission to use that command.`);

        }
    }
}
```

please help me
thank you

Comment: Please update your question with the full error message, there are too many id's in your code to know which is returning undefined. Also please specify what version of discord you are using (based on code it looks like v12)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the member's id, you need to `fetch` or `cache` it.

```
message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

Then to call the member. `message.user.id || message.id`